# loading a page with jquery script that include the same jquery script also

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATE:

I try to explain better my case: (sorry, it's very very difficult to me to explain in english).

I have mainpage.asp containing 10 divs.
The page loads jquery and loads myfunction.js in which is declared the following function in the document.ready:

```
// toggle
$("a.toggle-fx").click(function(){
    var x=$(this).attr("id");
    $("#x"+x).slideToggle(400);
    $(this).toggleClass('toggle-btn-active');
    }
);
```

Every divs is like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-btn toggle-fx" >open info</div>
<div class="toggle-content" id="xtoggle_[id]">
    [html content]
</div>
```

(*[id] is univoque for every divs)

The open info link works great: firs click opens, second click close.

After the 10 divs I have a button "loadomore" that calls a function to load "loadmore.asp" generates other 10 divs and appends this content in a box #moreresults on mainpage.asp, under the first 10 divs.

```
function loadmore(pag,pagnum,qcry){
    $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});
    $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: "loadmore.asp",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("#moreresults").append(msg);
        },
            error: function()
        {
            alert("loading failed.");
        }       
    });//ajax
}
```

This is workign fine. I display 10 new divs every click on loadmore button.

So, What's the problem? The problem is in the loadmore.asp page. I don't know how to let the new appended 10 divs use the toggle function declared in the main page.

- If in loadmore.asp I load jquery and myfunction.js, the toggle function works but is fired 2 times with a single click (box opens and closes immediately). I guess the reason is that I loaded the toggle function 2 times (in mainpage.asp in loadmore.asp)
- If in loadmore.asp I don't load/include jquery and myfunction.js, the toogle function doesn't work at all on the new 10 divs.

So the problem is that when I load with $.ajax a new content and append it on the main page, there is no sharing of jquery functions and my other functions declared in calling main page.

My target is to use $("a.toggle-fx").click(function() in the loaded and appended content.

thanks

Comment: I have to add that $("a.toggle-fx").click function is in $(document).ready.

Comment: can you please also appnend the Html / dom? also in the above question. At first sight it seems that toggleClass and  SlideToggle doing the same functionality.

Comment: There is less clarity with your question on what exactly is happening, perhaps provide more of your code. But I think you should read about `event.stopPropagation()` it might solve the issue.

Comment: I update the question, I hope is more clear.
@Shobhit Walia: toggleclass only changes the aspect of the button (open/closed)

Comment: The click event handler is not bound to your AJAX-loaded content because they are not present when the page is first loaded. You will want to look into using `.on()` to bind event handlers to dynamically-added elements—this means having to rewrite how event handlers are bound in your `myfunction.js`.

Comment: @Terry: ok I undestand but.. if I load myfunction.js with the dynamically-added elements (in the new page) it should bind the function to the new elements. And only one time. On the contrary it seems that also the first document.ready is valid for the added contents

Comment: You do no need to reload the JS file. Read up about `.on()` in the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/. Something like `$(document).on('click', 'a.toggle-fix', function() {...});`.